# Rails application <select> display overwritten

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, html

I have a Rails 3 application set to use HTML5. I previously programmed a select tag to display some values from an active record query. Now when I run the application the  default display is being set to none though I do not have that style attribute set in any of the application stylesheets. Even when I use in-line styling such as

```
<div id="models">
  <select style="display:block;">
    <% @models.each do |model| %>
        <option value="<%= model.id %>" ><%= model.name %></option>
        <% end %>
     </select>
   </div>
```

the element's style attribute is still being set to "display: none;".

Do anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: My only suggestions would be to restart your server, then disable JavaScript in your browser and see if it's any better.

Comment: There must be something somewhere that is setting that style. Use the Inspector (in Chrome) or FireBug (in FF) to find out if a css is setting display to none. Then check your js code for anything like `$('select').hide();`. Remove your stylesheets, then your javascript, looking for the bug. Basically, keep removing layers until the bug goes away - at that point, you've found it.

Comment: I came here to basically give the same comment as Jonathan.  Must be javascript setting this value if there are no inline or css styles.

Comment: Try <select style="display:block !important;">, to make sure it's not an inheritance/specificity problem. Also, to state the obvious...make sure you don't have any weird CSS for your #models div (negative z-index, display:none, etc).

Comment: When my code does something "impossible", I usually find I'm not running the code I think I'm running. Either that or Jonathan and Jason are correct about some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend trying collection_select, something like:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

e.g.

```
collection_select(:model, :name, Model.all, :id, :name, {:prompt=>true}, {:class=>'my-class'})
```

and set my-class in your stylesheet.